# How to initialize an array of struct in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I have the following `struct` in my C++ code (I am using Visual Studio 2010):

```
struct mydata
{
    string scientist;
    double value;
};
```

What I would like to do is to be able to initialize them in a quick way, similar to array initialization in C99 or class initialization in C#, something *á la*:

```
mydata data[] = { { scientist = "Archimedes", value = 2.12 }, 
                  { scientist = "Vitruvius", value = 4.49 } } ;
```

If this is not possible in C++ for an array of structs, can I do it for an array of objects? In other words, the underlying data type for an array isn't that important, it is important that I have an array, not a list, and that I can write initializers this way.

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't work... (btw that would be `.scientist = ...`) Have you tried?

Comment: @fge Yes, it's called aggregate initialisation and is further explained in detail  [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The syntax in C++ is almost exactly the same (just leave out the named parameters):

```
mydata data[] = { { "Archimedes", 2.12 }, 
                  { "Vitruvius", 4.49 } } ;
```

In C++03 this works whenever the array-type is an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special). In C++11 this works with any object that has an appropriate constructor.

Comment: I thought that _uniform initialization_ usually referred to the _list-initialization_ form (i.e. without the `=`)? I couldn't find a reference for uniform initialization in the standard.

Comment: @BjörnPollex It would not be a bad thing to re-mention, I think.

Comment: This appears to be a gcc extension. As far as I can make out, it's not standard C++ and is unlikely to work in other compilers. It doesn't work in Visual Studio, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, we must set the array size of `data` and it must be at least as big as the actual initializer list :

```
//          ↓
mydata data[2] = { { "Archimedes", 2.12 }, 
                  { "Vitruvius", 4.49 } } ;
```

Answer (score -3):

The below program performs initialization of structure variable. It creates an array of structure pointer.

```
struct stud {
    int id;
    string name;
    stud(int id,string name) {
        this->id = id;
        this->name = name;
    }
    void getDetails() {
        cout << this->id<<endl;
        cout << this->name << endl;
    }
};

 int main() {
    stud *s[2];
    int id;
    string name;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "enter id" << endl;
        cin >> id;
        cout << "enter name" << endl;
        cin >> name;
        s[i] = new stud(id, name);
        s[i]->getDetails();
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```