# C++ Shortcut with structs or arrays

Tags: c++

I do not know what this is called, I've seen something like it before. Where ever I had seen it, it said that it is not the best approach.

```
Items[0].x = 0; 
Items[0].y = 0; 
Items[0].width = 32; 
Items[0].height = 32; 
Items[0].name = "RandomName";
```

That is a better example. That is what I am doing. I was hoping there was a way to get around the Items[0]. prefix when entering the information.

Comment: Do you mean how to initialize structs?

Comment: You might be thinking of designated initializers from C: `struct StructOne test = {.a = 4, .b = 2, .c = 2};` (sorry if that's slightly wrong). However, there's still aggregate initialization: `StructOne test = {4, 2, 2};` and you can compose that with an array's initialization.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534526/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-struct-in-c You may also look up constructors and initializer lists.

Comment: I mean like:

       `struct a { int b; int c; };`


    `a test[2];`

    `with test[0] // the "with" being something else`
       `b = 5; c = 7;`
    `with test[1] `
       `b  = 56; c = 6;`

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+C then CTRL+V afterwards seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
test.a = 4;
test.b = 2;
test.c = 2;
```

Comment: I mean like:

       struct a { int b; int c; };

    a test[2];

    with test[0] // the "with" being something else
       b = 5; c = 7;

Comment: @EvanCarslake not c++, i'm afraid

Comment: I updated the first post, thats a copy and paste of what I am doing. Next entries would be Items[1] etc... I usually do it manually but I am hoping there is a quicker/ simpler way.