# c++ how to get data out of a hardcoded struct?

Tags: c++, struct, output, hardcoded

I have a struct that has hardcoded data in it, however I can't figure out how to get c++ to display the data. What I am trying is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 8;

struct test {
   int x[MAX] = { 16, 21, 308, 45, 51, 63, 17, 38 };
   float y[MAX] = { 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5 };
   int z[MAX] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
} id[MAX] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

int main() {
   for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX; counter++) {
       cout << id[counter].x << ", " << id[counter].y << ", "<< id[counter].z << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just like you use a loop to print the elements in the `id` array you need to do the same thing for the `x`, `y` and `z` arrays.

Comment: `struct test {int x[MAX] = { 16, 21, 308, 45, 51, 63, 17, 38 };`  you can not initialize a member in this way (at least in C)

Comment: Is there a reason for the `c`-tag or do you just find it aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534526/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-struct-in-c

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your data layout:

```
struct Triplet
{
  int x;
  float y;
  int z;
};
```

Next, make a container of the values:

```
std::vector<Triplet> test;
```

Or

```
  Triple test[MAXIMUM_CAPACITY];
```

This should make your initializations easier.
It may also speed up your program by keeping relevant data closer together in the data cache.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to get c++ to display the data.

You've been shooting over regarding usage of hardcoded arrays.
You don't need to double up your dimensions for `struct`. Any `struct` initialization will preserve the necessary memory for it's members.

You probably meant to write something like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 8;

struct test
{
   int x; // A simple int
   float y; // A simple float
   int z; // A simple int
} const id[MAX] = // Preserve the dimension. Note the const, to prevent changing the
                  // hardcoded values.
    // Initialize the triples as needed
    { { 16, 1.5, 8 } ,
      { 308, 2.5, 7 } ,
      // Place more triples here ...
      { 38, 8.5, 1 }
    };

int main()
{
   for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX; counter++)
   {
       cout << id[counter].x << ", " << id[counter].y << ", "<< id[counter].z << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/389af8ab7a93a81c)

---

The idiomatic c++ way to write this would be

```
struct test {
   int x; // A simple int
   float y; // A simple float
   int z; // A simple int
};

std::array<test,MAX> id {{
    { 16, 1.5, 8 } ,
    { 308, 2.5, 7 } ,
    // Place more triples here ...
    { 38, 8.5, 1 }
}};
```

See [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c977c428e766b04)